# Suspend/resume recently broke

Tags: suspend, power-management

I have a PC I built about a year ago, it's been working fine without issues, and suspend/resume from suspend has always worked great.  Just in the last week or so though suspend functionality broke.  In the past when I suspended my PC, the power light would eventually turn off.  Then in the future I could hit my keyboard or hit the power button once and the computer would turn back on and resume where it was.  Now, however, when I try to suspend, the screen goes black, but the power button never turns off.  If I hit a keyboard key or the power button again, nothing happens.  The only way forward is to hold down the power button until the computer forcibly turns off.

I suspect this broke when I did a recent software update - I hadn't run any updates in a few weeks so last week when I ran software updates there were a lot of packages that needed updating, including some core linux/ubuntu packages, though of course I don't remember the specific names or packages involved.

Output of `uname -a`:
`Linux Sonny 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Happy to provide any other info that would be helpful

Comment: Have you had a history of withholding updates? I understand you believe that an update caused your problem, but in fact it may be the opposite because your system appears to be very far behind on updates. If the version is being reported as 20.04.1, that means your system lacks updates that have been available since February 2021. It may seem counterintuitive if you believe updates cause problems, but keeping on top of updates is considered good maintenance and not doing so can cause problems sometimes. Can you update your system fully and see if the problem is resolved?

Comment: Also, are you using an official version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I always run all available updates every few weeks at max.  I definitely don't think my system is years out of date.  I literally just ran "Software Updater" and found 0 packages in need up upgrade.  I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Installed via boot drive made from official Ubuntu ISO download.